# AnyDice: Count successes plus a limited number of easier successes

Tags: statistics, anydice

I've been searching around but haven't yet found how to get this average out of AnyDice.

Players roll a pool of d6s. Normally, a success is counted on a 4, 5, or 6. However, there's a condition a player may have where a certain number of 3s also count as successes.

How can I get this into AnyDice? For example, what is the expected number of successes if I roll 3d6, but I can count up to two 3s as successes?

In other words: Total successes = 4s + 5s + 6s + (3s, but a limit of two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This [script](https://anydice.com/program/2ba97) works

```
function: successes in N:s up to M threes {  \ ':s' expects a sequence: the function is invoked for all possible sequences that can be made by rolling dice \
 result: [count {6,5,4} in N]               \ count 6s, 5s, and 4s \
       + [lowest of M and [count 3 in N]]   \ plus count at most M 3s \
}

loop N over {1..5} {
  output [successes in Nd6 up to 2 threes] named "Successes in [N]d6"
}
```

The key is to use the ':s' so that the function is called for each possible sequence that the dice can roll. From there it's easy to use '**count** values **in** sequence' and '**lowest of** number **and** number' to count successes with with an upper bound to 3s.

Here's the 'at least' results, for 1d6 through 5d6 (counting up to 2 3s):
[image: The average number of successes is: 0.67 for 1d6, 1.33 for 2d6, 2.00 for 3d6, 2.65 for 4d6, and 3.29 for 5d6]